# Strange behavior using Java ternary operator on Android

Tags: java, android

I don't know why but I am getting this strange error when I use a ternary operator on this example :

[image: Screenshot of the strange behavior of setInterpolator]

I think it's related to the way that Java cast the result from the operator but it only happen in some specific cases.

Thanks for any explanation.

Note : I searched for one but could only find NPE related answers.

-Edit-

The app uses :

- compileSdkVersion 23
- buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
- minSdkVersion 14
- targetSdkVersion 23
- Android Support Library 23.2.0

Test done on Android Studio 2.0 Beta 5 with the corresponding gradle version

Comment: which api level did you set for your app? because `LinearInterpolator` extends `BaseInterpolator` which [requires api level 22](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/BaseInterpolator.html)

Comment: Change minSdkVersion to 22...

Comment: it defenetly want you setup min api version to 22. becouse public void setInterpolator (TimeInterpolator value)  but you setup linearinterpolator which extends base interpolator

Comment: @KonstantinVolkov and BaseInterpolator extends Interpolator which implements TimeInterpolator. This should be working.

Comment: yep i see, but only from 22 api http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/BaseInterpolator.html  this is something strange may be it will ok if you setup you wil change build version to 21?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is because of the way ternary operators work.

It always casts both the Objects to it's **nearest** Super type common for both the objects.
In your case it's `BaseInterpolator`, because your targetSDK version is set to `23`.

But, since your minSDK is `14`, the cast will not work on all the devices. Hence the error.

To fix, you can add an explicit cast of `TimeInterpolator` to both the objects.

Comment: Didn't work for me: this time lint complained about casting BaseInterpolator to TimeInterpolator. But when I replaced ternary operator with plain 'if', the errors have gone. Isn't it strange?

Answer (score 0):

I fix this by code follow:

```
public class MyDecelerateInterpolator implements Interpolator {

    private DecelerateInterpolator interpolator = null;

    public MyDecelerateInterpolator() {
        interpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator();
    }

    public MyDecelerateInterpolator(float factor) {
        interpolator = new DecelerateInterpolator(factor);
    }

    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float input) {
        return interpolator.getInterpolation(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: I read the code of DeccelerateInterpolator. It implements BaseInterpolator and witch implements Interpolator. BaseInterpolator didn't add any abstract method. It means that these two classes have same abstract method named getInterpolation(float input). I don't know why the error is showed, but as long as the abstract method is the same, we can define a class witch implements Interpolator and wraps DecelerateInterpolator. Thus no more error shows.